# How to move a number of files to a directory only if their name exists in another directory of files, in one line?

Tags: unix, command-line, ubuntu-16.04

Imagine that I have three directories like this:

### Directory One: file1 file2 file3 file8

### Directory Two (tags): file1 file3

### Directory Three: empty

I want to check if the file exists in Directory Two move the file from Directory One to Directory Three, **in one line** if possible.

Final desired output:

### Directory One: file1 file2 file3 file8

### Directory Two (tags): file1 file3

### Directory Three: file1 file3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in directory2/*; do mv directory1/"$(basename "$file")" directory3/; done
```